# How can I rward Mails with Postfix and Dovecot to a specific Mailbox?

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, forwarding, mailbox

I can’t figure out how to forward mail withhPostfix and Dovecot to a specific Mailbox.

Sender Mail Address --> Mailbox of Receiver

At moment the mails are transfered into the INBOX of specific Users.

**Postfix configuration:**

Main.cf

```
lmtp_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/_virtual
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:10000
```

Virtual_alias_maps

```
@sender.org                        user@receiver.org
```

**Dovecot:**

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
  separator = /
  type = private
}
protocols = imap imap lmtp
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `virtual_alias_maps` command is designed to redirect an incoming message by recipient, not by sender, so yours would suggest user@recipient as a catchall address for mails directed to *@sender. Note that the file name must be the same as specified in main.cf, so `/etc/postfix/_virtual` in your case and you need to call `postmap` after every update.

If you want to reroute an incoming mail based on the sender address, you could try the following:

In `main.cf` modify the option `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` so that it contains `check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access`
Then create `/etc/postfix/sender_access` with a content like

```
sender.org REDIRECT user@receiver.org
```

(See [the postfix manual entry of Access(5)](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) for details on the file syntax.)

After that, run `postmap /etc/postfix/sender_access`, reload/restart your postfix and from now on, all incoming mail from the domain sender.org should be delivered to user@receiver.org, regardless of the TO, CC and BCC field.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer. You are right. Its the recipient not the sender.

Let me clarify my question.

How can I realise the following constalation?

Mail -> recipient address -> mail account account -> specific Mailbox